# How to include flags for valgrind in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, valgrind, flags

I have a makefile with a valgrind target that looks like this:

```
# expects a file `test.keys` to exist; it can contain any numbers.
valgrind: $(PROG) test.keys
    valgrind ./$(PROG) < test.keys
```

If I wanted to include valgrind flags such as `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all`, where would I put them? Do I put them right after `valgrind:`, or only on the second line before `./$(PROG)` but after `valgrind`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name "valgrind" appears twice in your rule because you are using it to mean two different things: it is the name of the analysis tool that you want to execute, and it is the name of *your makefile rule,* which is arbitrary. You could just as well have named your rule "pumpernickel":

```
pumpernickel: $(PROG) test.keys
    valgrind ./$(PROG) < test.keys
```

The flags are to be passed to valgrind (the analysis tool) as if you were invoking it on the command line. That's what the second line is; that line is passed to the shell as a command. So that's where the flags belong.

P.S. Whatever name you choose for this rule, be aware that by default Make expects a rule with a given name to build a file with that name. This rule builds nothing, so you should use [`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) to warn Make not to expect this rule to behave in the default way.